# Is a static variable created using a lambda thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, static

```
    A& instA()
    {
        static A a = []{
              return A();
         }();
         return a;
    }
```

**`instA()` returns a single static `a`; is this function multithread safe?**

Comment: may depend on code you did not post. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: this function in isolation is thread-safe, but any read/writes to the returned reference are not

Comment: thanks ,  i uncertain that the initialization of A is safe?

Comment: if safe, that can aviod use mutex?

Comment: Function-local static objects are thread-safe since C++11. Additionally, what you have here is a very contrived way of writing: `static A a; return a;`.

Comment: Initialisation of static objects local to functions is thread-safe, since C++11.   So your code to initialise `a` does not need to use a mutex.   However, the standard does not specify how that is achieved - it is not infeasible that the implementation (aka compiler and library) will use a mutex to ensure it is thread-safe.   And, as already noted, any use of the returned reference after the function returns is not thread safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, a simpler code that achieves the same is:

```
A& instA()
{
    static A a;
    return a;
}
```

Since C++11, this is thread-safe. No mutex needed inside this function. `a` will be created only once and different threads can get a reference to it.

However, don't make the mistake of believing the above solves all threading issues concerning `a`.

Two thread can do this:

```
  // thread A
  auto x = instA();

  // thread B
  auto y = instA();
```

But as soon as more than one thread accesses the instance and at least one writes, you need to synchronize the access. This is **not** thread safe:

```
  // thread A
  auto x = instA();
  x.foo = 42;

  // thread B
  auto y = instA();
  int y = x.foo;
```

In summary: Your `instA` is creating the instance in a thread safe-manner. Though, that does not imply that anything beyond creating the instance is thread safe. I would suggest to return a `const A&` instead.